# insert record with JPA having a field as an foreign key to another table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to insert data into a table and one of the fields is an FK to a different table. The problem is that using JPA and Criteria to perform the operations I would like to avoid having to fill out the entire child object to do so. 
Example:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="SENSOR_ID", nullable=false, updatable=false)
private Sensor sensor;

public Sensor getSensor() {
    return sensor;
}

public void setSensor(Sensor sensor) {
    this.sensor = sensor;
}

em.getTransaction().begin();
Measure m = new Measure();

m.setDeformation(measure.getDeformation());
m.setMoment(timestamp);
m.setTemperature(measure.getTemperature());
m.setTension(measure.getTension());
m.setSensorId(measure.getSensorId()); // I would like to do it like this and not having to use m.setSensor();

em.persist(m);
```

Comment: provide code for `m.setSensorId()` and Measure class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If sensor is mapped in Measure like in your example:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="SENSOR_ID", nullable=false, updatable=false)
private Sensor sensor;
```

You need to fill sensor instance. Sensor is not saved with measure because by default no operations are cascaded. It must be saved before calling this.

To not fill whole sensor, use sensor_id FK instead of Sensor in Measure class.

```
@Column(nullable = true)
private Long sensor_id;
```

To use both one must be read only:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="SENSOR_ID", updatable=false, insertable = false)
private Sensor sensor;
```

Comment: And how exactly would you implement the method setSensorId() ??
Also I got this when I tried to read the table:
Exception Description: Multiple writable mappings exist for the field [MEASURE.SENSOR_ID].  Only one may be defined as writable, all others must be specified read-only.

Comment: Is this what you suggest I do with the sensor_id column?? 

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

 @JoinColumn(name="SENSOR_ID", nullable=false,updatable=false, insertable=false)

 private Sensor sensor;

 @Column(nullable = true)
 private Integer sensor_id;

Comment: that WORKED! the only additional thing I had to do is implement the setter this way:

public void setSensorId(Integer sensorId) {
  this.sensor_id = sensorId;
 }